# Must input negatively multiple times to break out of loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a piece of code I made which works as expected except for the else branch. I have to type in a response without y 3 times to successfully go into that branch. Does anyone understand why that is happening?

```
def marker_question(position, marker_position):
    invalid_input = True
    while invalid_input:
        write("Would you like to do anything with the marker?")
        answer = input().lower().strip()
        if "y" in answer:
            write("Would you like to pick it up and place it or would you like to teleport to it?")
            answer = input().lower().strip()
            if "pick" in answer or "place" in answer:
              marker_position = position
              invalid_input = False
            elif "teleport" in answer:
              position = marker_position
              invalid_input = False
            else:
              write("That is not a possible action")
        else:
            write("You have decided to do nothing with the marker")
            invalid_input = False
    return position, marker_position
```

Here is an example image of input/output
[image: Test]

Comment: What, if anything, is the code printing out when you do this?   A transcript of a run exhibiting the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show the output/input of your program where you say you have to do it 3 times? To me it only seems like there would be a case where you would have to type something without `y` 2 times.

Comment: There are two `else` branches in this code.  Which are you referring to?

Comment: What is `write()`?

Comment: so to answer John Gordon write is a self defined print function which prints every character in the arguement with the tiniest time.sleep() in between which prints out things very aesthetically. Also I am referring to the last else statement.
To answer everyone else I will edit the question to have an example

Comment: There is no print that says "Would you like to go North or East?" in your source code.

Comment: this is only a section of the code that I have written but this is the section that is messing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue but try input with quotation marks
It's work for me
[image]

Check the input function if you use it right

Comment: strangely enough that works. Ill just make it so it adds that to the outsides of the input.